# Trying to disable “ignore ownership” option on NTFS partition, not much going right

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, partition, ntfs, diskutil

Cloned a Boot Camp partition from my old Mac with dd (both thus being NTFS), but, unlike the original, it does not show in the boot menu. Research suggests this is because ownership is disabled.

Thus I want to disable the "ignore ownership" option. Research finds two different ways: a checkbox in the "Get Info" section of the drive, which I don't have, and Terminal. The latter can achieve it either through "sudo vsdbutil -a [partition]" or through "sudo diskutil enableOwnership [partition]".
Except the first one finds "No such file or directory" whenever pointed to it, and the latter responds with "Error enountered enabling user/group ownership: The underlying task reported failure on exit (-69860)".

So, what am I to do?
Thanks to anyone who'll help me out.

Specs: Mid-2015 MBP 15", Mojave (10.14.6).

**Chapter 2:**

As per requested by David Anderson, diskutil output from the new Mac with the old one's drive plugged in from USB adapter:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS MarSSD                  389.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                109.6 GB   disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         407.9 GB   disk1s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                91.9 GB    disk1s3

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +407.9 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk1s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh SSD - Dati    3.8 GB     disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 92.1 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                525.8 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      8.6 GB     disk2s4
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh SSD           11.2 GB    disk2s5
```

Comment: Have you used BootCamp (or some other util) to create a Windows boot partition? Without a Windows boot partition that behavior makes perfect sense.

Comment: @SteveChambers what I have cloned WAS my Windows boot partition. The Boot Camp assistant did not work for me (the "Continue" button was literally linked to nothing) so I created a new partition, formatted it to NTFS, and cloned my old Mac's Boot Camp partition into it. But now it's bootable no more, and having heard that ownership has to be enabled for bootable partition I am suspecting it to be the culprit.

Comment: Windows boots on a Mid-2015 MBP 15" from the existing EFI partition. Nothing in your question states you written any boot code to the EFI partition.

Comment: @DavidAnderson but even then, will it boot with ownership disabled?

Comment: The ownership issue is irrelevant with respect to booting Windows.

Comment: @DavidAnderson thanks, but how do you write boot code to the EFI partition? Do you use the Boot Camp assistant? And if so how?

Comment: Which version of Windows? What is the model/year of the old Mac? Did you `dd` from partitions of exactly the same size? Can you post to your question the output from `diskutil list` from both Macs?

Comment: @DavidAnderson In order: Early 2013, same otherwise. Larger target partition. Done!